# Subproject does not fetch dependencies from Super POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I got the following scenario:
`diag-parent` (Super POM) and `diag-domain` (child)

SUPER-POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.dbsystel.udg</groupId>
        <artifactId>udg-super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>de.db.udg.diagnose.udg-diagnose</groupId>
    <artifactId>diag-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.20.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>diag-domain</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.db.kolt.alice</groupId>
                <artifactId>alice</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- PrimeFaces File Upload utils -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Child POM:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.db.udg.diagnose.udg-diagnose</groupId>
    <artifactId>diag-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>diag-domain</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
...
</project>
```

Compiling the diag-domain module results in:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project diag-domain: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Projekte/FA-DIAGNOSE/UDG-DIAGNOSE/branches/Richface_Migration/impl/diag-domain/src/main/java/de/db/udg/diagnose/udgdiag/domain/base/ToManyAssociationModel.java:[13,28] package org.primefaces.model does not exist
```

It obviously doesn't fetch *any* dependency from `diag-parent`. Even my .m2 repository is empty.

The effective pom of `diag-domain`:

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated on 2020-01-09T11:13:57                                       -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'de.db.udg.diagnose.udg-diagnose:diag-domain:jar:1.20.16-SNAPSHOT'     -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.db.udg.diagnose.udg-diagnose</groupId>
    <artifactId>diag-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>de.db.udg.diagnose.udg-diagnose</groupId>
  <artifactId>diag-domain</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>diag-domain</name>
  <description>domain objects</description>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      ...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      ...
</dependencyManagement>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Entries inside `<dependencyManagement>` are not dependencies. They are just standard versions for dependencies.

Dependencies need to be in the `<dependencies>` tag *outside*  of `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: Yes, I would add specify the dependency version in `<dependencyManagement>`, and just include groupId/artifactId (no version) in `<dependency>`

Answer (score 3):

As you only used `dependencyManagement` the dependencies are not imported.
You need a `<dependencies>` section in the child pom and there you enter the dependency.

`<depenencyManagement>` is only used to tag some versions of the dependencies for all submodule usage.

See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

> When you have a set of projects that inherit from a common parent, it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs

Comment: How can I globally declare the dependencies, since multiple projects use primefaces jar.

Comment: Put a `<dependencies>` section into your parent POM (outside of the `<dependencyManagement>` section).